# How to disable pagination on mysite.com/checkout/cart/ page?

Tags: cart, pagination

Doase anybody know how to disable pagination on mysite.com/checkout/cart/ page ?

[image]

I Want all my cart items to appear on the same page.

How to do it using XML config ( if possible ) ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: an image will talk more than this. :) please share screenshots.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want to use config.xml file? Just ask because the config setting does it's job :)

Answer (score 6):

**Follow this step**

> Stores > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart > Number of
>   Items to Display Pager = **0**

Comment: Do you know how to disable it from layout xml ? Thanks!

Comment: Ronak, I'd like to accept your answer, but please say how to do int from the XML. Thanks!

Comment: I tried but i did't find any solution using .xml file.

Comment: I tried too before posting this question. Let's hope someone will give us the answer.

Comment: @Supersonic if you really need this disable functionality using .xml than edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Create your module with **sequence** from **Magento_Checkout**:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Override default configuration value:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <checkout>
            <cart>
                <number_items_to_display_pager>0</number_items_to_display_pager>
            </cart>
        </checkout>
    </default>
</config>
```

Don't forget clear cache.
Write me if you have any issues.

Comment: This sets only the default value, but when you save config section with a different value it's overriden. Or am I wrong?

Comment: No, you are right

Comment: Just say why it is so and I accept your answer. Thanks!